# How to match a newline \n in a perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to match this line,

```
<center>'''<font color="blue"><font size="18.0pt">No Change Alarms Help &amp; Information</font></font>'''</center>
```

and replace it with,

```
=<center>'''<font color="blue">No Change Alarms Help &amp; Information</font>'''</center>=
```

Now it would be simple if the tags were always font colour or center, but they can be absolutely anything and there can be multiple of them.

My current code is this:

```
$html =~ s/<font size=".+">(.+)<\/font>/$1/g;
```

but this obviously does not do the = on each end.

What I would like to do is this:

```
$html =~ s/\n(.+)<font size=".+">(.+)<\/font>(.+)\n/=$1$2$3=/g;
```

However it fails to match the newline characters and I cannot figure out how to make it match them, any clues?

(I'm converting html to wiki markup, however the converter stuffs up the font sizes so I'm manually converting them to wiki style headings.)

Comment: The accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) is applicable here.

Comment: I guess the first sanity check I'd want to ask myself is: are the newlines actually in the source AND do I want to get rid of them?
I realise this may not help you but it's hard to know your exact situation. (For example, does it fail to match them EVERY time, or every second case, etc? Also, does $html represent the whole page or part of?) ALSO yeah, use an XML parser ;)

Comment: XML parser is generally the right tool, however in this case of parsing a very limited subset of HTML and hundreds of megabytes of data regex was not only more appropriate but much faster.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All I needed was `/gm` on the end of my query, turns out it ignores new lines by default.

Comment: This can't be the answer to your question. The `/g` makes all possible matches, and the `/m` only affects the `^` and `$` anchors, which you don't use. The `/s` lets the `.` match a newline.

Answer (score 11):

In some cases it might not work because of how perl "slurps" the input. Passing `-0777` as a parameter will make it consider multiple lines. (Pass it along with your other parameters, e.g. `perl -0777pi -e`)

Answer (score 0):

```
$string_given =~ s/matching expression/sustitution/s;
```

i think this will work,using the /s modifier, which mnemonically means to "treat string as a single line". This changes the behaviour of "." to match newline characters as well.

In order to match the beginning of this comment to the end, we add the /s modifier like this:

```
$str =~ s/<!-- Start.*End of section -->//s;
```

Without the /s, it wouldn't match at all.

Comment: The `/s` allows the `.` to match a newline. That's all it does. That's a bit different than treating the whole string as a single line, which is more like what already happens and what `/m` turns off so `^` and `$` can match around a newline (hence, multi-line string).