# Perl match newline in `-0` mode

Tags: regex, perl, newline

### Question

Suppose I have a file like this:

```
I've got a loverly bunch of coconut trees.

Newlines!

Bahahaha
Newlines!
the end.
```

I'd like to replace an occurence of "Newlines!" that is surrounded by blank lines with (say) NEWLINES!. So, ideal output is:

```
I've got a loverly bunch of coconut trees.

NEWLINES!

Bahahaha
Newlines!
the end.
```

### Attempts

Ignoring "surrounded by newlines", I can do:

```
perl -p -e 's@Newlines!@NEWLINES!@g' input.txt
```

Which replaces all occurences of "Newlines!" with "NEWLINES!".

Now I try to pick out only the "Newlines!" surrounded with \n:

```
perl -p -e 's@\nNewlines!\n@\nNEWLINES!\n@g' input.txt
```

No luck (note - I don't need the `s` switch because I'm not using `.` and I don't need the `m` switch because I'm not using `^`and `$`; regardless, adding them doesn't make this work). Lookaheads/behinds don't work either:

```
perl -p -e 's@(?<=\n)Newlines!(?=\n)@NEWLINES!@g' input.txt
```

After a bit of searching, I see that `perl` reads in the file line-by-line (makes sense; `sed` does too). So, I use the `-0` switch:

```
perl -0p -e 's@(?<=\n)Newlines!(?=\n)@NEWLINES!@g' input.txt
```

Of course this doesn't work -- `-0` replaces new line characters with the null character.

So my question is -- how can I match this pattern (I'd prefer not to write any perl beyond the regex 's@pattern@replacement@flags' construct)?

Is it possible to match this null character? I did try:

```
perl -0p -e 's@(?<=\0)Newlines!(?=\0)@NEWLINES!@g' input.txt
```

to no effect.

Can anyone tell me how to match newlines in perl? Whether in `-0` mode or not? Or should I use something like `awk`? (I started with `sed` but it doesn't seem to have lookahead/behind support even with `-r`. I went to perl because I'm not at all familiar with awk).

cheers.

(PS: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495791/how-to-match-a-newline-n-in-a-perl-regex) is not what I'm after because their problem had to do with a `.+` matching newline).

Comment: "-0 replaces new line characters with the null character." is not true. Try `perl -MO=Deparse -0pe'...'` to see effect of `-0`.

Comment: @ikegami Where can I read about this "-0" mode of perl? I don't know what to google..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following should work for you:

```
perl -0pe 's@(?<=\n\n)Newlines!(?=\n\n)@NEWLINES!@g'
```

Comment: Huh, I just tried what I tried earlier and it worked. I must have been mashing keys earlier :P (also, thanks for picking up the `\n\n`). cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If the file is small enough to be slurped into memory all at once:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n\nNewlines!(?=\n\n)/\n\nNEWLINES!/g'
```

Otherwise, keep a buffer of the last three lines read:

```
perl -ne 'push @buffer, $_; $buffer[1] = "NEWLINES!\n" if @buffer == 3 && ' \
      -e 'join("", @buffer) eq "\nNewlines!\n\n"; ' \
      -e 'print shift @buffer if @buffer == 3; END { print @buffer }'
```

Comment: cheers, I forgot to mention the files will always be big enough to read entirely into memory. One question -- what's the `-0777`? I know `-0` but not of `0777`.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee `-0` takes an argument in the form of an octal, and 777 is by convention used as a sufficiently large number to cause file slurping.

Answer (score 1):

I think they way you went about things caused you to combine possible solutions in a way that didn't work.

if you use the inline editing flag you can do it like this:

```
perl -0p -i.bk -e 's/\n\nNewlines!\n\n/\n\nNEWLINES!\n\n/g' input.txt
```

I have doubled the \n's to make sure you only get the ones with empty lines above and below.

Comment: Thanks for that, I just tried typing it in again (the `-0` with the `\n`) and it worked. I feel like a monkey at a typewriter sometimes....